# How can I set custom value in "created_in" when customer data import in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend, custom, import

I need to set custom value in this field "created_in" when customer data import using admin side how can I set the custom value in that .

[image]

[image]

I need to set custom value in that can any one guide me how can I archive this when customer data import from admin using CVS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download sample CSV from Magento (System -> Data Transfer -> Import). Select like screenshot[image]
2. You can able to see the created_in column[image]
   Use same way, will work.

Comment: but i need to do using coding